# Trying to understand the output in notebook out cell

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I don't understand the point of the out cell. It seems to be a char count?! Any way to get rid of this altogether?

[screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrsVH.png)

I am using gophernotes (notebooks for golang)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually expected. In the [official documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/fmt#Println) it says

> Println formats using the default formats for its operands and writes to standard output. Spaces are always added between operands and a newline is appended. It returns the number of bytes written and any write error encountered.

Thus, what you are seeing is the actual output followed by the number of bytes and the error, which is just `nil` in your case (no error as expected).